# WordPress Gutenberg blocks: How to restrict page-level blocks, but allow all child-level blocks

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

In a WordPress plugin I have created some custom 'layout' Gutenberg blocks. These are basically 'boxes' that contain the rest of the page contents. I'd like to restrict the user to adding only these boxes into a page, but then allowing them to place *ANY* child blocks within them.

I have found [how to limit Gutenburg blocks](https://walterebert.com/blog/limiting-wordpress-gutenberg-blocks/) using the `allowed_block_types` filter. This works to just restrict the user to adding 'boxes' to a page.

I have then found how to limit a Gutenberg block to only allowing specific child blocks. i.e. on InnerBlocks, specify `allowedBlocks: ['core/paragraph','core/list','core/seperator',...]` so that the 'boxes' can contains these child blocks.

The problem is that the allowed_block_type filter seems to override the allowedBlocks.

How can I allow specific blocks at 'page' level, and others at the 'child' level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crossposted from my [answer on WordPress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/353485/gutenberg-restrict-top-level-blocks-but-not-child-blocks/353640?noredirect=1#comment516507_353640)

The short answer is you can’t. But you can accomplish this by using a block template that only contains your block and is locked. If your block has an InnerBlocks instance, you can add any of the registered blocks to it.

```
add_action( 'init', 'insert_template' );
function insert_template() {
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( 'post' );
    $post_type_object->template =[ [ 'your-custom-block-name'] ];
    $post_type_object->template_lock = 'all';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom script to the admin panel using the `admin_enqueue_scripts` action.

Here is an example of how you can restrict existing blocks to only be included inside certain blocks:

```js
const restrictEditorParentBlocks = (settings, name) => {
    const TEXT_EDITOR_BLOCKS = [
        'core/heading',
        'core/image',
        'core/list',
        'core/paragraph',
        'core/shortcode',
        'core/embed',
    ];

    if (TEXT_EDITOR_BLOCKS.includes(name)) {
        settings.parent = ['example/my-custom-block-that-needs-text-editor-blocks']
    }

    console.log(settings, name)

    return settings
}

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.registerBlockType',
    'your-project-name/restrict-parent-blocks',
    restrictEditorParentBlocks
);
```

This will disable them for the page, but allow them inside the specified parent blocks.

(see `settings.parent` assignment)